# How to calculate Cumulative Sum in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I know how to do cumulative sum if dataset has Dates, But I am struggling to do same if I do not have dates in my dataset.

Below is the data, I want CUM Sales

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've selected New quick measure -> Totals -> Running total and creates this:

```
sales running total in part = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Query1'[sales]);
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Query1'[part]);
        ISONORAFTER('Query1'[part]; MAX('Query1'[part]); DESC)
    )
)
```

Returns:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create own measure to calculate cumulative sum.

Select New Measure from the ribbon and write the following expression

```
Cumm Sales = 
        VAR Current_Part = MAX(Test[Part])
        RETURN
        CALCULATE(
                  SUM(Test[Sales]), 
                  Test[Part]<=Current_Part, 
                  ALL(Test[Part])
                 )
```

Output:

[image]